# Button in ButtonGroup href property changes right border

Tags: material-ui

With MUI 5.0.2, The `href` property of `Button` in a `ButtonGroup` changes the `Button`'s right border.

When there's no `href`, the right border will not show up. It will show up on hover.

It is said by @Ryan Cogswell, that the styling for the border is using `:not(:last-of-type)` in the selector. This implies that MUI is using class on  and , which seemes very slopy to me.

Is this is a bug?

I hosted a [minimal environment with GitHub Pages](https://pablion.github.io/pablion-questions/MUI_PCS). The question is shown on the first and last chapter.

(picture 2 and 4 are the same)

[image: Button with href]

Button with href

[image: Button without href]

Button without href

[image: Button without href on hover]

Button without href on hover

[image: Element with no href]

Element `<Button />` with no href

Also I made a [related issue on official repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/28899), and in my [Learning note](https://github.com/Pablion/Pablion/wiki/MUI-%28aka-Material-UI%29-learning-note#question-howwhy-does-the-props-affects-the-style-on-buttongroup-and-iconbutton)

Comment: Your issue is missing a code sandbox (which is requested by the issue template). A code sandbox would also be useful here.

Comment: The right border is supposed to be missing for buttons in a button group other than the last button -- otherwise you get a double border between buttons (I don't think it is intended to be used with icon buttons). The presence/absence of the "href" prop impacts the behavior because the styling for the border is using `:not(:last-of-type)` in the selector. When `href` is present, it will render an `a` tag, otherwise a `button` tag, so when the right border is present for a button in the middle it is probably due to using both element types within the group.

Comment: Actually I just moved from code sandbox, because of the slow updating speed. It takes five or ten times longer than running locally. I thought was that running locally would be easier to test for you to test as well. I guessed the `last-of-type` thing too, but making `<a/>` and `<button/>` same types seemes very slopy to me, so maybe this is a bug?

Comment: No, running locally doesn't make it easier for me or for the MUI team looking at an issue. I don't want to install anything locally -- I just want to click on the code sandbox link. As far as whether this is a bug -- I don't think so. You're just using ButtonGroup in a way that it wasn't intended to support. None of the examples in the docs use icon buttons. One example does wrap an icon in a regular `Button`. The docs indicate that the immediate children of a `ButtonGroup` should be `Button` elements.

Comment: MUI v5 docs also has StackBliz demos, from my limited experience it's faster than Codesandbox so you may want to give it a try.

Comment: @Ryan Cogswll. I tested your reason by adding a `Button` without `href` in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69488977/iconbutton-in-buttongroup-has-unstable-style) and it shows `IconButton` and `Button` without `href` will both have `button` as root node, and they share the same type for `:last-of-type`. So you are correct. Can you answer the question so I can close it.

Comment: I will try StackBliz and move all there if it works well. Then update this question. Thanks @NearHuscarl (also for the other question you answered).

Comment: @NearHuscarl StackBliz doesn't support the lastest MUI, v5.0.3, nor v5.0.2. I don't think it's a best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expalained by the comments of @Ryan Cogswell, I collated this answer.

- The styling for the border is using `:not(:last-of-type)`(guess: on `<button>`).

  - `IconButton` have root node of `<button>`.
  - In `Button`, if `href` is defined, an `<a>` element will be used as the root node (otherwise a `<button>`), said in [official doc](https://mui.com/api/button/#props).
  - This explains these two questions:

    1. Property `href` changes the right border of element, because it changes the `<button>` to a `<a>`
    2. When all `IconButton`-s are on one side, other `<Button>`-s have `href` property, the hover background shape of last `IconButton` will change, because this would change the result of `:not(:last-of-type)` CSS query on `<button>`-s.