# IconButton in ButtonGroup has unstable style

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

With MUI 5.0.2, When all the `IconButton`-s in a `ButtonGroup` go on the same side, the hover background shape will change.
And other elements also affects this (a `Button` with/without `href` property on one side)

It is said in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69488393) by @Ryan Cogswell, that the styling for the border is using `:not(:last-of-type)` in the selector. This implies that MUI is using class on  and , which seemes very slopy to me.

Is this is a bug?

I hosted a [minimal environment with GitHub Pages](https://pablion.github.io/pablion-questions/MUI_PCS). The question is shown on the first and forth chapter.

(all pictures shown here are showing with on hover)

[image: Button with href]

Button with href

[image: Button without href]

Button without href

[image: buttons all together]
Button without href on hover

Also I made a [related issue on official repo](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/28899), and in my [Learning note](https://github.com/Pablion/Pablion/wiki/MUI-%28aka-Material-UI%29-learning-note#question-howwhy-does-the-props-affects-the-style-on-buttongroup-and-iconbutton)

Comment: Please don't add text as images, google can't read that and it's also harder to copy the text.